# How can I achieve only one possible selection similar to radiogroup in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

How can I achieve only one single selection similar to a group of radio buttons using a list of views in SwiftUI?

[image: sample ss]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When a button is pressed, you can store the value for which one was selected.

And you can style the buttons based on which one is selected.

The following code should do what you're looking for. Whichever button is last pressed will be selected, and only the selected button will be blue, because the styling is based on the property. And another button clears the selection.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let buttons = ["A", "B", "C"]
    @State public var buttonSelected: Int?

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            ForEach(0..<buttons.count) { button in
                Button(action: {
                    self.buttonSelected = button
                }) {
                    Text("Button \(self.buttons[button])")
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .background(self.buttonSelected == button ? Color.blue : Color.green)
                        .clipShape(Capsule())
                }
            }
            Button(action: {
                self.buttonSelected = nil
            }) {
                Text("Clear Selection")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: My pleasure! And I don’t normally ask, but I’m a few reputation points shy of being able to comment on another issue I’ve been following, so I could use an upvote on the answer. Cheers!